# Return Values from User Control Dialog Box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to implement a dialog box to ask the user for an input. I created a usercontrol and bound the data context to a ViewModel. I ask the user to select an item from a list. I want to pass that selection back to the Main program.

```
try
{
    var ins = from Instrument in InstrumentList where Instrument.Comport == result.Comport select Instrument;
    result.OperatorName = ins.FirstOrDefault().OperatorName;
    result.OperatorID = ins.FirstOrDefault().OperatorID;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Open a control to prompt for instrument.
    Window window = new Window
    {
        Title = "Associate Com Port",
        Content = new MyDialogView(),
        SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
    };
    window.ShowDialog();
    //var inst= ValueFromDialogBox
    //WriteInstrumentToConfigFile(inst);
    //Set proper Instrument/Comport pair
    GetAdditionalData(result);
}
```

So what I need is the ValueFromDialogBox. I wouldn't mind being able to get more than one value. If I can pass back an object then I can do whatever I want.

Here is the XAMLfor the dialog (MyDialogView)

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:MyDialogViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>    

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./MainWindowResources.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Background="AliceBlue">
        <Run Text="What instrument are you using?" />
    </TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Background="AliceBlue">
        <Run Text="Select the Instrument number from the list."/>
    </TextBlock>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="1"
             SelectedItem="{Binding InstrumentSelected}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfInstruments}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Here is the View Model (MyDialogViewModel)

```
    public class MyDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Fields
    string prompt;
    string comResponse;
    string comport;
    private string selectedInstrument;
    private ObservableCollection<string> listOfInstruments;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Prompt 
    {
        get { return prompt; }
        set 
        { 
            prompt = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();

        }
    }

    public string ComResponse
    {
        get { return comResponse; }
        set 
        { 
            comResponse = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();

        }
    }

    public string ComPort
    {
        get { return comport; }
        set 
        { 
            comport = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string InstrumentSelected
    {
        get { return selectedInstrument; }

        set
        {
            if (value == selectedInstrument)
                return;
            selectedInstrument = value;

            base.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfInstruments
    {
        get { return listOfInstruments; }
        set
        {
            listOfInstruments = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();

        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands


    #endregion

    #region Methods



    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public MyDialogViewModel()
    {
        listOfInstruments = new ObservableCollection<string>{
            "Instrument 1", "Instrument 2", "Instrument 3", "Instrument 4"
        };
    }

    public MyDialogViewModel(ref MainWindowViewModel mwvm)
    {
        listOfInstruments = new ObservableCollection<string>{
            "Instrument 1", "Instrument 2", "Instrument 3", "Instrument 4"
        };
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If you want us to help  you get "the ValueFromDialogBox", please make an effort to tell us what  "the ValueFromDialogBox" is. Is it a property of the window content? If you want us to help you find properties of the window content, you'll have to tell us something about the window content, and its properties.

Comment: It is a property. It is a string from a list box. The ListBox SelectedItem is bound to the ViewModel property SelectedInstrument. The ListBox is populated when the ViewModel gets instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Open a control to prompt for instrument.
Window window = new Window
{
    Title = "Associate Com Port",
    Content = new MyDialogView(),
    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
};
window.ShowDialog();

//  The view is the window content.
var view = (MyDialogView)window.Content;

//  The view XAML created an instance of MyDialogViewModel and assigned it to 
//  the view's DataContext.
MyDialogViewModel dlgVM = (MyDialogViewModel)view.DataContext;

//  Now you've got the viewmodel that was used in the dialog, with all its 
//  properties intact. 
MessageBox.Show($"Instrument selected was {dlgVM.InstrumentSelected}");
```

How to close the window in this case:

UserControl XAML:

```
<StackPanel 
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        Content="_OK"
        Click="OKButton_Click"
        />
    <Button
        Content="_Cancel"
        IsCancel="True"
        />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind in the user control:

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.GetWindow(sender as DependencyObject).DialogResult = true;
}
```

The cancel button works if you just set `IsCancel="True"` on it. `ShowDialog()` will return false in that case. In the case where you set `DialogResult` explicitly, `ShowDialog()` will return the bool value you assigned to `DialogResult`, unless it's `null`. `DialogResult = null` won't close the window.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. Now to close the dialog. I used the window close X to step through it. What I need to do now is implement an OK button just to close the dialog. But I got the important part thanks to you.